# error when import GoogleAnalitics from "@next/third-parties/google"

Tags: javascript, next.js, google-analytics

I want to use googleAnalytics in my project.
According to the next js document,

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/third-party-libraries#google-analytics

I imported GoogleAnalytics, but it gives me an error that something like this has not been exported from this path.

note: im using javascript not typescript

I expected it to work without any error but it gives me this error :
error message
Attempted import error: 'GoogleAnalytics' is not exported from '@next/third-parties/google' (imported as 'GoogleAnalytics').

Import trace for requested module:
./src/app/layout.js

Answer (score 0):

`GoogleAnalytics` was added in the [canary](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@next/third-parties?activeTab=versions) release. simply upgrade `@next/third-parties` to the latest canary version:

```js
npm i @next/third-parties@14.0.5-canary.59
```

And then imports should work as expected:

```
import { GoogleAnalytics } from "@next/third-parties/google";
```

Tested and working on `next 14.0.4`